# Prove that entire function satisfying this is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

This question was part of an assignment which I am trying to solve but couldn't.

> Let f be an entire function such that $\frac{f(z) } {z} \in 0$ as $  |z|\to \infty$ . Show that f is constant.

Entire function means that f is holomorohic on all of $\mathbb{C} $ but what result can I use? One can also proceed by assuming that f is not constant. But in this way also I was unable to find a contradiction.

Kindly help!!

Comment: I think this question has already an answer here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745437/if-f-is-entire-and-lim-limitsz-to-infty-fracfzz-0-show-that-f

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $f$ is entire and $\lim_\limits{z\to\infty} \frac{f(z)}{z} = 0$ show that $f$ is constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745437/if-f-is-entire-and-lim-limitsz-to-infty-fracfzz-0-show-that-f)